# capturing pva multiline compiler output for emacs compile mode

Tags: emacs, compile-mode

I wish to compile hSpice pva through emacs.
However, compile-mode does not parse the output properly.

This is the error message the pva compiler generates (the pvaE section):

```
Parsing include file 'include/constants.vams'
Parsing include file 'include/disciplines.vams'
*pvaE* Syntax error, unsupported syntax or illegal keyword at/before 'vco_cal_dec'
    file "/my/path/to/file/veriloga.va", line# 226

  (ari_var>=0 ari_var<= 7) : ari_var2=16;
              ^
```

This is the compile mode settings that fail to capture the above output:

```
(defvar verilog-compilation-error-regexp-alist '("^\*pvaE\* .+\n\s+file \"\\(.+\\)\", line# \\([0-9]+\\)"  1 2))
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist  verilog-compilation-error-regexp-alist)
```

Help fixing this regexp will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace syntax in your string is wrong.  Instead of "\s+" it should be "\\s-+".

Comment: Also the `\*` should be `\\*`. In Emacs, string literal syntax and regexp syntax is completely independent, so you need a backslash in the regexp, and another backslash to protect it in the string literal.